# react-native-image-viewer - Landscape View didn't work on IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

On Android, Landscape-Mode works like a charm, but on IOs I've found following issue:

Mobile-Device is in Landscape-Mode:

- I click on an Image (Touchable-Opacity set the state modalShow
  The Landscape-Mode will be switched to Portrait-Mode, after that the Modal appears
- If I close the Modal, the App switch back to Landscape-Mode.

Any Idea, why this only happend on Iphone, but working well on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this (or only some of them like you're needs) to your Modal, which encapsulate the Image-Zoom Component:

```
supportedOrientations={
 [
   'portrait', 
   'portrait-upside-down', 
   'landscape', 
   'landscape-left', 
   'landscape-right'
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library to manage the screen rotation https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation